# Get a random element from a sequential collection

Tags: java, iterator

I talk to an API that gives me an `java.util.Iterator` over a collection. That means I can iterate over it but I can't get direct/random access to the elements.

Now to my problem: I want to get one random element from this collection. How do i do that? I guess I could build a new collection that allows direct access, but isn't that a little memory consuming? I could also iterate over the entire collection and for each element "roll a dice" to see if I should take that element and quit iteration or continue. But then I need the size of the collection and I can't get that from the Iterator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The collection normally shouldn't be the class that implements `Iterator`.

Comment: Is your collection a `java.util.Collection`?

Comment: The memory consumption shouldn't be all that large.  The new collection just holds pointers to the actual data, so the size of the new collection object != the size of the collection.

Comment: @Jonathan B In pathological cases the collection contain many duplicate elements or `null`s, which could make an `ArrayList` of the collection relatively large.

Comment: @thejh It's my clumsy writing, thanks for mentioning it. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a way to do it on one pass through the collection that doesn't use a lot of extra memory (just the size of one element of the collection plus a float).  In pseudocode:

- Iterate through the collection.
- For each item, generate a random float.
- If the float is the lowest (or highest, it doesn't matter) one you've seen so far, store the current item from the collection in a temporary variable.  (Also store the new lowest random value.)
- Once you reach the end of the collection, you have a random item in the temp variable.

Obviously this has the drawback of iterating through the entire collection every time you call it, but you don't have a lot of choice with the constraints you're facing.

**Update:** The name of this type of problem finally came back to me.  This is called [Reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

Comment: Much the same as my solution (other than I'm not using floats (btw, ints would do better)).

Comment: @Tom: That does look like pretty much the same basic idea.  Why is `int` better, though?

Comment: @Bill the Lizard An int would give you a bigger spread of values for a given number of bit. Don't have to deal with all that IEEE guff.

Comment: @Tom: Oh, that.  I was expecting some arcane trivia about `Random` that I didn't know yet.  :)

Comment: I may have got my math wrong, but I think that this will not uniformly select over the list.  To prove this, think about how this will work for 3 items.  First item is selected with 100 % probability.  Second item is selected with 50% probability (so far so good), but the third item will only be selected with 25% probability, not 1/3 probability as it should be.

Comment: @Dean: The third random number from a RNG has a 1/3 chance of being the lowest.  Every number has an equal probability of being lowest (or highest), so this will work no matter the size of the collection.

Comment: @Dean Povey Look at it this way: Before you look at the sequence generate the random numbers. The highest always occurs at a uniformly random position.

Comment: I think you are both wrong.  For any two random items there is a 50% chance that one will be higher than the other.  For two items it works, but for the third item it has to be higher than _both_ the other items, ie. you have to mulitply the probabilities, therefore it has only a 25% chance of being higher than both the first two numbers.

Comment: @Dean: You don't have to multiply the probabilities.  It's not coin flips, it's a uniform distribution of values.  Any one of them has a 1/n chance of being the highest.

Comment: And by higher I meant lower :-) (or higher, as your answer suggests)

Comment: @Dean Povey: "For any two random items there is a 50% chance that one will be higher" is wrong. "Nearly 50%" would be correct. They could be equal, right? ;)

Comment: @Bill, okay forgive me for being a n00b. I just counted the permutations properly and realized that you are right. There are two ways out of 6 that the 3rd number can be greater than the other two.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard Thanks, this is exactly the solution that I couldn't wrap my head around by myself.

Comment: If you read the wikipedia page linked from the answer you will see that you have to decrease the probability of each answer being the one selected as you iterate. Otherwise you create bias towards the end of the iteration order.

Answer (score 7):

When iteration, you know how many objects you've iterated through, so you know the probability that the current element is the one to select randomly. So you just need to keep hold of a count and the current randomly selected item.

```
public static <T> T selectRandom(final Iterator<T> iter, final Random random) {
    if (!iter.hasNext()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (random == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    T selected = iter.next();
    int count = 1;
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        final T current = iter.next();
        ++count;
        if (random.nextInt(count) == 0) {
            selected = current;
        }
    }
    return selected;
}
```

(Stack Overflow Disclaimer: Not compiled, and certainly not tested.)

See also the section about `Collections.shuffle` in Java Puzzlers.

Comment: I don't how this is random: with every iteration, probability that `random.nextInt(count) == 0` is lower and lower.

Comment: When I pass in a list with one item, there's one iteration. `count` gets the value `2`. In half of all cases, `null` will be returned for a list with one element, right? So this is wrong.

Comment: @tulskly Yes, when you to, say, the tenth element, then it has the probability of being selected as 1/10.

Comment: @thejh The first element is a special case in the code. (It could be done within the loop, but that would be icky code.)

Comment: @MRalwasser You might want to think about it some more. For every next element, there is a probability that the previous selected item is displaced. Comes out as fair.

Comment: @Tom You're right - I made a mistake during understanding your code. Thank you for pointing this out. +1

Comment: Is it possible to express the proof mathematically? I still cannot understand why this is fair, sorry. Very elegant solution though, if it is proven, I will praise you :).

Comment: @voho It's effectively the same as the [later] accepted answer. Proof as the outline in the linked Wikipedia article, only simplified because you don't need to a step for the probability that the last random number was most extreme.

Comment: OK, thanks for the tip, I will look at it. It is a little bit confusing because a set does not have any start or last element.

Answer (score 2):

The only safe solution (in case no further information is known/guaranteed) is the way you described:
Create a `List` from the `Iterator` and pick a random element.

If the size of the underlying collection is always the same you can reduce the effort by a half in an average - just use the element you got after Iterator.next() after a random number of iterations.

**BTW**: Are you really using a Collection which implements `java.util.Iterator`?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the requirements, if the size of the collection is not huge then this will do it, otherwise you should you iterate and use the dice method you mentioned

```
List<Object> list = Arrays.asList(yourCollection.toArray(new Object[0]));
result = list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Used this for generating weighted test data. it's not efficient but is easy

```
class ProbabilitySet<E> {

    Set<Option<E>> options =  new HashSet<Option<E>>(); 

    class Option<E> {
        E object;
        double min;
        double max;

        private Option(E object, double prob) {
            this.object = object;
            min = totalProb;
            max = totalProb + prob;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Option [object=" + object + ", min=" + min + ", max=" + max + "]";
        }
    }

    double totalProb = 0;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    public void add(E object, double probability){
        Option<E> tuple = new Option<E>(object, probability);
        options.add(tuple);
        totalProb += probability;
    }

    public E getRandomElement(){

        double no = rnd.nextDouble() * totalProb;
        for (Option<E> tuple : options) {
            if (no >= tuple.min && no < tuple.max){
                return tuple.object;
            }
        }


        return null;  // if this happens sumfink is wrong.

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProbabilitySet [options=" + options + ", totalProb=" + totalProb + "]";
    }

}
```

NOTE: the probability parameters will be relative to the total not to 1.0

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProbabilitySet<String> stati = new ProbabilitySet<String>();
    stati.add("TIMEOUT", 0.2);
    stati.add("FAILED", 0.2);
    stati.add("SUCCESSFUL", 1.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(stati.getRandomElement());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't have any random access, and you have a very large list so you can't copy it then you can do the following:

```
int n = 2
iterator i = ...
Random rand = new Random();
Object candidate = i.next();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    if (rand.nextInt(n)) {
        candidate = i.next();
    } else {
        i.next();
    }
    n++;
}
return candidate;
```

This will retain a random element from a list, but requires you traverse the whole list.  If you want a truly uniformly distributed value you have no choice but to do this.

Alternatively, if the number of items is small, or if you want a random permutation of a list of unknown size (in other words you want to access all the elements of the list in a random order), then I recommend copying all the references to a new list (this will not be a significant amount of memory unless you have millions of items since you are only storing references).  Then either use get with a random integer or use the standard java.util.Collections shuffle method to permute the list.

Comment: So much the same as my solution.

Comment: Yes. You added it while I was typing :-).